# How to install pbr module manully?

Tags: python-3.x, setup.py

I'm installing `python-jenkins` manually by downloading the module and using `python setup.py install`. `pbr` is one of the dependency for that. I have tried to do the same step for `pbr` also i.e download the project zip from GitHub and  `python setup.py install`, but facing the
error

```
$ python setup.py install
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 21, in <module>
    **util.cfg_to_args())
  File "C:\Users\shivansh.trn\Desktop\pbr-master\pbr\util.py", line 256, in cfg_to_args
    pbr.hooks.setup_hook(config)
  File "C:\Users\shivansh.trn\Desktop\pbr-master\pbr\hooks\__init__.py", line 25, in setup_hook
    metadata_config.run()
  File "C:\Users\shivansh.trn\Desktop\pbr-master\pbr\hooks\base.py", line 27, in run
    self.hook()
  File "C:\Users\shivansh.trn\Desktop\pbr-master\pbr\hooks\metadata.py", line 26, in hook
    self.config['name'], self.config.get('version', None))
  File "C:\Users\shivansh.trn\Desktop\pbr-master\pbr\packaging.py", line 849, in get_version
    name=package_name))
Exception: Versioning for this project requires either an sdist tarball, or access to an upstream git repository. It's also possible that there is a mismatch between the package name in setup.cfg and the argument given to pbr.version.VersionInfo. Project name pbr was given, but was not able to be found.
```

I can't use `pip install python-jenkins` or `pip install pbr` directly due to internet restrictions.

Comment: What is the internet restriction?  **Note:** Github is not usually an "enduser ready" version of the project, it's usually the development version, so the install is not the same as what you would do from the PyPi release or that pip does. **Note also:** If your issue is needing a proxy for pip, that is easy to resolve...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error when installing pbr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19087562/error-when-installing-pbr)